# Trim line from beginning and after certain expression

Tags: regex, regsub

I have a string "GET /testline HTTP/1.0#015#012U".
String always start with "GET ", and always contains "HTTP/1.0". 
Word "/testline" maybe various length and contains symbols and digits.
I need trim string to "/testline" (cut "GET " at the beginning, and cut "HTTP/1.0" and all other symbols after) using regex
How I can do this with regex?

Comment: You can try to use https://regex101.com/ to play around with your string and find a regex matching only what you want. This might be done in two steps as the part after "HTTP" might be matched as well if your regex only tries to match "/testline".
By the way, trimming is the process of removing *whitespaces* around a string, not other characters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

`(?<=GET )\S+(?= HTTP\/1\.0)`

`(?<=GET )` is **Positive lookbehind** - Matches a group **before** the main expression without including it in the result

`(?= HTTP\/1\.0)` is **Positive lookahead** - Matches a group **after** the main expression without including it in the result.

Notice: there is a space `" "` after GET and before HTTP

```js
const regexPattern = /(?<=GET )\S+(?= HTTP\/1\.0)/g
const paragraph = 'GET /testline HTTP/1.0#015#012U';
const found = paragraph.match(regexPattern);

console.log(found)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I try this Pattern here https://regex101.com/r/A0r1M5/1
I will use him in regsub to replace characters with ''. Expected result after replace is "/testline". So I need an inverted version. I need select all before and after "/testline"